# Could not locate property of name

Tags: stripes

Continuously displaying in server logs why these INFO are displaying logs please help me any one.  log file size increased and getting memory leak. I really appreciate any one respond

- Could not locate property of name [gstCategory-3355753] on ActionBean.net.sourceforge.stripes.util.bean.NoSuchPropertyException: Bean class com.casb.stripes.sep.PrReqSupActionBean$$EnhancerByGuice$$ed30caad does not contain a property called 'gstCategory-3355753'. As a result the following expression could not be evaluated: gstCategory-3355753

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are feeding an action bean (com.casb.stripes.sep.PrReqSupActionBean) a parameter (gstCategory-3355753) that it doesn't know about (not declared in the class definition). It duly reports that it refuses to deal with that, and no variable binding occurs.

You could solve this by not feeding that action bean the parameter with the form submission request, declaring the field in the action bean, or tightening logging to WARN, up from INFO.